# Posting SNS message to HTTPS Api Gateway endpoint to trigger Lambda function

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to trigger a Lambda function in Account2, region2 from Account1, region1 .

So, I use an SNS topic subscribed to an HTTPS API Gateway endpoint (POST method), which will trigger the Lambda.

The problem is that I do not know how to grab the SNS POST request arriving at the API Gateway endpoint .

I am trying to follow [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html#SendMessageToHttp.prepare) from the AWS docs.

I have successfully test the connection between Gateway and Lambda. 
I use this dummy JSON:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "description": "A subscription confirmation message",
  "properties": {
    "SignatureVersion": {
      "enum": [
        "1"
      ],
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Timestamp": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "MessageId": {
      "type": "string",
      "identity": true
    },
    "SubscribeURL": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Token": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Signature": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Message": {
      "minLength": 1,
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 4096
    },
    "Type": {
      "enum": [
        "SubscriptionConfirmation"
      ],
      "type": "string"
    },
    "TopicArn": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 1224
    }
  }
}
```

And the test Lambda I use is this:

```
import boto3,json

def handler(event, context):

    #return event['properties']['SubscribeURL']
    return event
```

The docs state [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/json-formats.html#http-subscription-confirmation-json) that `After you subscribe an HTTP/HTTPS endpoint, Amazon SNS sends a subscription confirmation message to the HTTP/HTTPS endpoint.`

I don't necessarily want to have a piece of code to confirm the subscription every time because I will only set the flow once. But, I somehow need to take the subscription URL in order to confirm the subscription.

Any pointers would be helpful!

Comment: Why not subscribe the Lambda function directly to the SNS topic as an event source, as described here? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-create-x-account-permissions.html

Comment: I have tried it but as i understood , both the SNS topic and Lambda function must be in the same region. My use case is to take a manual snapshot of an RDS instance in us-west-2, share it with another account ,so it will be visible in us-west-2 in the 2nd account, and then  copy it in us-east-1 in the 2nd account. The Lambda that handles the copy (according to the docs) must be in the region that the copy will live.

Answer (score 0):

What problem are you trying to solve specifically? You should be able to invoke a Lambda function across accounts using [temporary credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/prog-services-sts.html). You could also publish to an SNS topic directly from your [Lambda function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-create-x-account-permissions.html), so you probably don't need API Gateway.

Comment: I have two accounts. I want an SNS from 1st account, Oregon to trigger a Lambda function in 2nd account,Virginia . I don't really care about the means. I am just searching for a way.

Comment: See links above. You will need SNS to trigger a Lambda function in the same region. From that Lambda function, you can assume temporary credentials in the other/account region and invoke the second Lambda function directly.