# Can an SNS trigger an API gateway? If yes, then how can the API gateway subscribe to the SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns

I need to create an API gateway to consume messages from an SNS. I see that there are some questions on the same, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41720243/5345646), which hasn't been answered directly.

The main issue I face is : How to make the API gateway subscribe to the SNS?

Comment: Question why only API gateway ? Why can't be Lambda. Because API is public endpoint. Whatever you are going to do can do Lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SNS supports [HTTP/HTTPS endpoint subscriptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.subscribe.html). So I don't see a reason why you could not subscribe API gateway https endpoint to SNS this way.

Comment: Hey @Marcin, thanks for the answer! Okay I see that it's doable. But how exactly can I confirm the subscription for the gateway? I see that for [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.prepare.html) is the doc provided by AWS for subscriptions. Do we have to do the same thing for API gateway here, or do we have something simpler?

Comment: @Mooncrater I guess you would have to hook up lambda to confirm subscription. I don't know exact details, as I haven't done such a subscription myself. You can try and see how it will go.

Comment: Sure sure. Will look creating a lambda for the subscription.

Answer (score 2):

As Marcin has mentioned, it can be done. Mentioning the steps I used:

- Create SNS, and a lambda
- Whatever the language is, make sure to print the event in the log. (For JavaScript, use `console.log(event)`, and for Python use `print(event)` etc)
- Create an API Gateway (REST API), select a "New API", and create it.
- In the API create a POST method, select lambda, and make sure to use it as a proxy.
- Copy the trigger HTTPS link
- Add a HTTPS subscription in the SNS, and use the trigger link here.
- The confirmation would be pending now.
- Go to the lambda, inside it's monitoring section, go to cloud watch logs.
- Inside the logs, you will find the event object printed. Inside it, look for `SubscribeURL`, along which the URL would be mentioned.
- Copy this URL, and go back to the SNS. Select your subscription and use the "Confirm Subscription" option, and paste this link there.
- The status should come as "Confirmed" now.

Comment: Hello. I tried to do this but wasn't able to achieve. The subscription confirmation is pending even though I am not receiving it in cloud watch logs. The regions for SNS/lambda/Gateway are the same one. Did you make any extra step like adding some policies?

Comment: When you attach lambda to API gateway, it does ask for permissions. So did you give those?

Also if you see the logs, and message from SNS is present, then using the subscription URL, it should work. If it doesn't do let me know I'll look into that.